# Issues with nested for loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, ssh

From a central Linux box (RHEL 6.3) I'm attempting to push a set of zip files to a series of other Linux hosts and then unzip those files on each target host. My central host is hpdb1.

```
#Push zip files to other hosts
for i in {2..8}; do
    scp -r /software/stage/*.zip root@hpdb$i:/software/stage
done

#Unzip files to /software/stage
for i in {2..8}; do
    ssh hpdb$i "for f in /software/stage/*.zip; do unzip /software/stage/"$f" done";
done
```

The first for loop to push the files works fine. However, when running the nested for loop I get the following error:

```
[root@hpdb1 ~]# for i in {2..8}; do ssh hpdb$i "for f in /software/stage/*.zip; do unzip /software/stage/"$f"; done"; done
unzip:  cannot find or open /software/stage/, /software/stage/.zip or /software/stage/.ZIP.
unzip:  cannot find or open /software/stage/, /software/stage/.zip or /software/stage/.ZIP.
```

Looks like the `$f` variable is not getting interpreted. Any ideas?

## Updated for answer

This code works.

```
for i in {2..7}; do
    ssh hpdb$i 'for f in /software/stage/*.zip; do unzip "$f" -d /software/stage; done';
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be the nested double-quotes.  You probably want the outer quotes to be single-quotes so that the embedded `$`s are not expanded before getting sent to the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

My first though is to use the other quote character like, so:

```
for i in {2..8}; do ssh hpdb$i 'for f in /software/stage/*.zip; do unzip /software/stage/“$f”; done'; done
```

Comment: i was just going to write this as a comment on the original question. i think this is the answer, try it out!

Comment: Rob and DopeGhoti, You guys were mostly right, but got me on the path to righteousness...

The single quote allowed the files to be found, but when it ran, I got the following error: unzip: cannot find or open /software/stage/software/stage/p13390677_112040_Linux-x86-64_1of7.zip

So I then changed the syntax to hpdb$i 'for f in /software/stage/*.zip; do unzip “$f”; done'; done

That worked, but it unzipped everything to /root

Modifying it further to use the -d flag for unzip worked like a champ!

hpdb$i 'for f in /software/stage/*.zip; do unzip “$f” -d /software/stage; done'; done

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use different quotes as suggested by another answer, this will alter variable expansion behaviour and may be undesirable in some cases.

You can simply escape the enclosed quotes instead, by pre-pending them with a backslash:

```bash
for i in {2..8}; do 
  ssh hpdb$i "for f in /software/stage/*.zip; do unzip /software/stage/\"$f\"; done";
done
```

Comment: "Although you could use different quotes as suggested by another answer, this will alter variable expansion behaviour..." But that's  exactly what is needed here.